# Draggable UIView on ScrollView user experience not good

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, button, draggable

I have a UITableView, on each cell, I have a draggable button.

The draggable button is a subclass of UIButton, and override below delegate functions:

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

First of all, this button works and is draggable as expected. The problem is, the `touchesBegan` delegate is only called when user really **tap** on the button. **Since this button is on a UITableViewCell, if user's finger fling really fast over the button, the `touchBegan` function couldn't be called everytime, instead, the table scrolls some times.**

I have tried to use `UIEdgeInsetsMake` to optimize the button touch area, but still this issue exists. I am not sure what could be a good way to improve this experience.

Comment: By implementing the `touches...:withEvent:` methods, you have effectively bypassed all behavior of scrollviews and gesture recognisers. If I may ask, why did you? I mean, why not add a `UIScrollView` inside the cell, and let the scroll view help you out with the dragging?

Answer (score 1):

try set the `@property(nonatomic) BOOL delaysContentTouches` of your UITableView to `NO`

Answer (score 0):

While planting the button. 
set this property.

```
myButton.layer.zPosition = 10;
```

and I think you should check your Event Control and properly place it according to your need.

```
 UIControlEventTouchUpInside // fires when u release press
 UIControlEventTouchDown // fires at the instant you press it down.
```

There are a few more and i think you should consider them accordingly.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can override hitTest:withEvent: on the tableview.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect buttonArea; //figure out rect 
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(buttonArea, point))
    {
        return button;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This will make the touch go directly to your button instead of going to the scroll view first.

More on this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html

Answer (score -1):

You should use UIPanGestureRecognizer for detecting touches and moves by finger inside your button's rect. 
And you can enabled delaysTouchesBegan property for disable scrolling.